# Как можно развернуть данную рекурсию?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, числовые-последовательности

Задача в том, чтобы быстро находить n-тый член [последовательности Голомба](http://oeis.org/A001462).

Но вариант находить последовательность полностью с помощью ДП и брать `dp[n]` не подходит, так как затратит больше положенных `255 Мб`, т. к. `n <= 2e9`.

А рекурсивное решение неподходит, т. к. рекурсия выходит слишком глубокой.
Возможное решение проблемы - разворот рекурсии.

Как это можно реализовать?

P.s.: Так же на нахождение элемента последовательности даётся порядка одной секунды на не самом сильном железе.

```
findGolomb(int n) {
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    return 1 + findGolomb(n -
               findGolomb(findGolomb(n - 1)));
}
```

Comment: Для какого предельного n ищем?

Comment: Не думаю, что развёрнутым циклом можно будет удовлетворить условие по времени. В принципе, в последовательности проглядывает явная закономерность. Так как математику я люблю, то скоро приду с ответом

Comment: @Harry: там написано: `2е9`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Закономерность наблюдается конечно, на oeis.org есть даже формула, но она "примерная", содержит дроби и на каких-то неизвестных мне тестах округляется неправильно.

Comment: А зачем вам нужна эта последовательность? А еще было бы неплохо добавить описание последовательности в вопрос, а то ссылки имеют тенденцию протухать.

Comment: @VTT Просто решаю задачу, суть которой в поиске n-того элемента этой последовательности. На самом деле, задача интересная, с учётом того, что в сети я не нашёл ни одного решения, которое бы быстро находило точный ответ для больших n.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понятно, по какому принципу выбирается указанная там последовательность среди множества других, удовлетворяющих тому же условию. Почему не `1 3 2 3 2 2 5 4 4 4 ...` например? Там есть комментарий про минимальность чисел, но нужно ли это?

Comment: Кажется, у меня есть ответ (на моем железе отрабатывает за ~1мс  для n=2e9). Осталось убедиться в его правильности. Минут через 20 (когда удастся сравнить результаты рекурсивного и моего методов) дам ответ

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Вы оптимист, если считаете, что рекурсия за 20 минут дойдет до 2*10^9 :)  А до 10000 - возьмите тут: http://oeis.org/A001462/b001462.txt

Comment: @VTT Данная последовательность неубывающая и единственная в своём роде среди неубывающих.  
`It is understood that a(n) is taken to be the smallest number >= a(n-1) which is compatible with the description. In other words, this is the lexicographically earliest non-decreasing sequence of positive numbers which is equal to its RUNS transform.`

Comment: Увы, мой вариант не подходит, у меня закралась ошибочка в логике. Думаю, следует все же посмотреться в сторону формулы

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Формула не подходит по причине того, что формула имеет только приблизительную точность. В итоге на каких-то неизветсных тестах программа даёт неправильный ответ, судя по всему, вследствие погрешности формулы и погрешности операций с дробными числами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось!

2е9-ый элемент на моей машине находится за 0.024 сек.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Elem
{
    int index = 3;
    int value = 2;
};

int FindGolombImpl(Elem *data, int size, int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;

    if (size <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Not enough storage!\n";
        std::exit(1);
    }

    while (data->index < n)
    {
        data->value++;
        data->index += FindGolombImpl(data+1, size-1, data->value);
    }

    return data->value;
}

int FindGolomb(int n)
{
    // Минимальное значение, которого хватает для вычисления 2e9-ого члена, подобрано методом тыка.
    constexpr int storage_size = 8; 
    Elem storage[storage_size];

    return FindGolombImpl(storage, storage_size, n);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << FindGolomb(2000000000) << '\n';
}
```